# c# Threading locking for 2 fields of a class

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

The question is easy, suppose I have:

```
class MyClass
{
    object myObj1
    object myObj2
}

Thread1(MyClass c)
{
    DoALotOnMyObj1(c.myObj1);
}

Thread2(MyClass c)
{
    DoALotOnMyObj2(c.myObj2);
}
```

Do I have to use locks in this case, even if I'm totally sure that both threads will use only myObj1 (or 2 depending on thread) and not the other field?

Comment: Is that a typo? Isn't thread 2 supposed to be doing `DoALotOnMyObj2(c.myObj2);` instead?

Comment: Yes it's a typo, thanks for notice

Comment: You only need a lock if myObj1 and myObj2 interact in some way that could cause conflicts when used simultaneously.  If the two objects are isolated from one-another, you're safe.

Comment: You could even pass the same object to both threads without having to lock anything if you'd knew that no "write" operations would be performed on that object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you would not.

Answer (score 1):

The concept of having a lock is to make sure that while you are changing a resource in one thread, other threads do not access it until the lock is released.

In your case, you are not sharing any resources between the two threads, so you don't need to have a lock.